# MS Access: Convert filtered split form with combo boxes to a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am once again stuck with Access given my lack of knowledge of both the software and VBA/SQL.

After having struggled to create my own VBA code to create a filter form, I decided to resort to a previously created form where the user can find all the relevant information from many tables aggregated there. This form also includes a split form, making it quite easy to filter data.

Among other things, I would like to be able to print a report based on this filtered data - this was fairly easy until I decided to filter a combo box.

In my main table I have several foreign keys linking to other tables, yet in the form I do not present the FK/PK. I created a combo box that displays the meaning of the PK/FK, which is what also appears on the datasheet portion of the split form. When I try to print the report (via a button), a parameter box pops up asking to input some value for the combo foxes used to filter.

Is there a way to solve this? I would like for my report to print the field with the meaning of the PK/FK if possible, otherwise it's not useful for the user. In other words, how do I make the report pull the PK/FK but present the field with the corresponding meaning?

(The report is able to pull this value perfectly when the datasheet portion is not filtered.)

Kind regards,

Laisinco

Comment: Please share with us the line of code (and its sql) that is causing the popup box. Or the short subroutine surrounding it.  What number of Filters are there? Does popup happen for any one filter or just a certain one filter? Or are two filters required to cause popup?  How are these filters applied?

Comment: @donPablo First of all, I am filtering the data using the datasheet portion of the split form (using the columns, as if it were excel), although using an advanced filter by form yields the same results. The number of filters doesn't really matter to cause this enter parameter popup, it only occurs if I filter one of those combo boxes which display a value in another table, but store a value from the main table (PK/FK).

Comment: @donPablo The only code I have in this form, besides some buttons I created to move between records is a button to open the preview of the report. A private sub when clicking the button, then OpenReport in preview mode, then If Me.FilterOn Then // With Reports![Report_Name] //.Filter=Me.Filter // .FilterOn=True // End With // End If

Comment: @donPablo By the way, I just checked that the message that appears in the popup is: Lookup_NameOfComboBox.NameOfFieldDisplayed. I don't know if this might be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the value in Me.Filter right when it is moved into .Filter ??  Can you put a break point there or debug.print the value?  Does the popup occur at OpenReport  or at  .Filter=Me.Filter  or at  .FilterOn=True ??

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I was able to find a crude workaround. I added a repetition of the combo boxes but as text boxes this time, thus they would appear twice in the datasheet portion of the split form. I hid the original combo box columns in the datasheet and left only the text box copies. Now I am able to filter and print the corresponding results, albeit filter by form no longer works, since the initial problem remains.

Comment: That seems to follow the example of  http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html